# Symfony Doctrine not working when uses "SEQUENCE" as GeneratedValue in Oracle

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following Entity in Symfony 2 with an ID generated by an Oracle Sequence:

```php
namespace PSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="CONTRATO")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PSBundle\Entity\ContratoRepository")
 */
class Contrato
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_CONTRATO", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SID_CONTRATO", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $idContrato;

    // Other fields...
}
```

But when I do:

```php
$entityContrato = new Contrato();
// Set some fields
$em->persist($entityContrato);
```

I get:

> Entity of type PSBundle\Entity\Contrato is missing an assigned ID for
> field  'idContrato'. The identifier generation strategy for this
> entity requires the ID field to be populated before
> EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
> identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
> accordingly.

I know that `SID_CONTRATO` is well defined as if I select the NEXTVAL it works:

[image: SID_CONTRATO works]

What I'm missing? Any kind of light in the subject would be more than appreciated, my related dependencies are:

```
"php": "7.2",
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.42",
"doctrine/orm": "2.3.x-dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.0",
```

**Doctrine config (from `config/config.yml`, I don't have a `doctrine.yaml` file)**:

```yaml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   oci8
        port:     1521
        dbname:   ORCL
        host:     %dbal_host%
        user:     %dbal_user%
        password: %dbal_pass%
        charset:  UTF8
        memory: true

        logging: true

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# IMPORTANT: this fixes bugs with the date format that is brought from Oracle ('d/m/y')
# The problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723240/symfony-doctrine-oracle-datetime-format-issue 
services:
    oracle.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

Comment: Hi @WillB. I've udpdated the question with that info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem:

If I do a `var_dump()` in `doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php` of `$class->idGenerator` it outputs:

> object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator)

While if I do the same with entities that currently work with sequences they output:

> object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\SequenceGenerator)...

So Symfony wasn't getting the correct type of Generator. I check the entity file and found out that there was some fields with `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")`, eg.:

```php
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ID_CONTRATO", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SID_CONTRATO", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
 */
private $idContrato;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="TIPO", type="string", length=1, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")  // This was the conflicting line
 */
private $tipo;
```

Apparently, Symfony gets the last `@ORM\GeneratedValue` definition as the class identifier generator, which in this case had the `strategy="NONE"` so It couldn't get the next value from the sequence.

Comment: For reference, Doctrine processes the annotations as a mapping for your entity. Symfony just wires the resulting Doctrine services.  I recommend reporting your findings to the Doctrine project so that they can update their documentation or resolve the error reporting, since the specified strategy should be called on the field in which it was declared on and the error should be reported from the `tipo` field instead.

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8980) submitted!